# Is the composition of a finite branched cover and a non-isotrivial Riemann surface bundle still non-isotrivial

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, fibre-bundles

Given $E\to B$ a non-isotrivial (compact) Riemann surface-bundle (of genus $g>1$) between two complex manifolds and $E'\to E$ is a finite branched cover. Then is the composition map $E'\to E\to B$ still non-isotrivial?

Comment: The only interpretation of "nonisotrivial Riemann surface-bundle"  that isn't contradictory is  a bundle in the $C^\infty$-category but not in the holomorphic category. Is that what you mean? $E'\to B$ needn't be a bundle, because it could have singular fibres. If you remove them, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @DonuArapura Yes, I meant it's only in the $\mathbb C^\infty$-category and I have removed the bundle assumption. Now is that possible for you to explain why the answer is yes? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E'$ is isotrivial, then the fibers $E'\to B$ are all isomorphic to a single fiber, so the Jacobians of every fiber are isomorphic to a single Jacobian abelian variety $A$. Then the Jacobian of every fiber of $E \to B$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $A$.  But $A$ has only countably many distinct quotients, up to isomorphism, while by the Torelli theorem a non-isotrivial family of Riemann surfaces has uncountably many Jacobians.

Probably there's a deformation theory argument that also works here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I am not very familiar with the Jacobian theory. Is that possible for you to explain why " the Jacobian of every fiber of $E \to B$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $A$"?

Comment: @6666 Given a map between two curves, we have a map between their Jacobians, which is always surjective. For example, viewing the Jacobian as the space of degree 0 divisors up to rational equivalence, this map corresponds to pushforward of divisors.